# revert pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus

Tags: 14.04, ssh, pkexec

me and my friend were playing around with each others system, and to display a particular pop up on her window through ssh, i used the command

`pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus`

But now she cant log in using GUI.. can anyone help revert back the effect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution guys..

All i had to do was remove all the .Xauthority files

`rm ~/.Xauthority*`

and restart the system..